# Change the url in Wordpress admin bar

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change the link at wordpress admin bar. I want the Link of `Database` (ie. `/wp-admin/`) to `/wp-admin/index.php`

What I try:

I try changing the link [`admin_url()` to `admin_url('index.php')`  at `/wp-includes/admin-bar.php`

```
.
.
// We're on the front end, link to the Dashboard.
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
            'parent' => 'site-name',
            'id'     => 'dashboard',
            'title'  => __( 'Dashboard' ),
            'href'   => admin_url('index.php'), // 'href'   => admin_url(),
        ) );
.
.
```

This did not work. How could I do it?

I need to go to `/wp-admin/index.php` as it says redirect loops on `/wp-admin/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rather fix your redirect loop problem before is escalates? I've often seen that happen when `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` was on but the Site didn't understand it was being requested via SSL ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] doesn't exist or isn't "on").

However, you could also circumvent that redirect loop by adding

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/$ /wp-admin/index.php [R=302,L]
```

in your .htaccess before the WP-rules.

Comment: Thanks this solve the infinite loop. And the code on my `What I try` works now. It changes the url :).